# Google Cloud Platform - Stackdriver Trace List all empty

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Google App Engine application that is listed under the Stackdriver Trace, but when I go to trace list there is nothing.

However, the logs and error reporting works.

Is there a special setting you need to set in order to get the traces? I've looked through many tutorials and it seems that the traces automatically appear?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackdriver Trace is not automatically setup for Compute Engine, App Engine Flexible or Containers. Stackdriver Trace is automatically enabled for App Engine Standard.

You must instrument your application first, then you can review the Stackdriver Trace logs.

Start with this link. Instrumentation is language specific:

[Setting Up Stackdriver Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/)

Comment: I'm using Python 3 + Flask for my GAE Flexible environment. It seems that there are no Stackdriver Trace instrument for Python.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/cloudtrace/v1